# how to manage forbidden acces s to id.archive.ubuntu

Tags: apt, permissions

> I tried update my ubuntu 22.04, but this is what i got:
> how to maintenance this?

> Err:4 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
> 403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.180.254 80]
> Err:6 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
> 403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.180.254 80]
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> E: The repository 'http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is no longer signed.
> E: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.180.254 80]
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> E: The repository 'http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
> E: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.180.254 80]
> E: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.180.254 80]
> E: The repository 'http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease' is no longer signed.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
> E: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.180.254 80]